# subdomains apache rewrite rules

Tags: apache, redirects, dns, subdomain, mod-rewrite

Let's say I have my web folder as public_html. In there I have a sub folder. I can view the folder at:

`www.mydomain.com/sub` & `mydomain.com/sub`

What I want is:

```
sub.mydomain.com
```

This will show the content of `public_html/sub`. How would I set up my rewrite rules to do this.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167068/apache-mod-rewrite-a-subdomain-to-a-subfolder-via-internal-redirect - useful info available there.  FWIW, my suggestion is you create another virtual host pointing directly to the sub-folder rather than incur the overhead of the apache rewrites.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any rewrite rules. Just add a [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) section, like

```
<VirtualHost IPAddress>
    ServerName sub.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/public_html/sub
</VirtualHost>
```